# Is this game fair?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have to do a project for math and I dont know how to find the probability.  I am shooting foam bullets at a target with 6 possible areas you can hit. The biggest area you can hit has a circumference of 90.275, the next one is 64.37, then 37.68, 17.27, 6.28, finally the bullseye is 1.57.  I do not know if this game is fair or the probability of winning.  Also, there are two players. Please help!!

Comment: To decide whether the game is fair you need more information.  Specifically, you would need the exact probability of hitting each area on the board, you would need the prize money for hitting each area, and you would need the cost to play the game.

Comment: @Java, since we're talking about a bullseye, it's reasonable to assume that the areas are concentric rings, so the (outer) circumferences are all you need to calculate areas. Then, one can make the (not-all-that-plausible) assumption that the probability of hitting each area is proportional to the area. But even with this interpretation, your other points are valid, and need to be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

One assumption we must make is that all shots hit the target somewhere - nothing misses completely. Unless you can supply us with the probability of missing, we must assume this is 0%.

The probabilities of each can then be computed by their relative areas.

A second assumption is that the smaller regions must be completely contained within the next larger region. Yes? This is somewhat open to interpretations, I suppose.  They could each be outside of one another. Either way, it changes their relative areas.

Without payouts for each, there is no way to determine fairness.  Fairness is a number that is computed from the combinations of probabilities and the relative winnings/losses associated with those probabilities.